# Autosize resizes the form to nearly 0,0

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, window-resize

I have a Form within a datagridview. I docked the datagridview in the center, so it fills the whole form. This works so far. I have a static amount of rows, 4, and i want the form to automatically resize, so that you cant see the grey bottom of the datagridview. I tried to do this by setting autosize = true in the form and also growandshrink. But when I start my form, it shrinks to nearly 0,0. Why doesnt it shrink to the optimal size of the datagrid view?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this to adjust the height of the form:

```
'calculate the size of the titlebar and border
Dim formBorderHeight = (Me.Height - Me.ClientRectangle.Height)
'adjust the height of the form to the height of the datagrid (assumes each row is the same height)
Me.Height = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + (DataGridView1.RowCount * DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height) + formBorderHeight
```

This won't work if you have scrollbars visible on the datagrid so you may need to adjust for those as well

Comment: Isnt there an easier way? I just want my datagridview as small as possible, as it does when I set Autosizecolumnsmode = allCelss. Underneath that I want just one button. Then the form should autosize itself as small as possible with not ignoring the datagridview (it looks like he is ignoring it, because he sizes depending on where i put my button, but the datagrid is ignored). This is a pretty easy layout, there must be an easy way with docking, anchoring?

Comment: I don't think so. This is pretty easy though - its only two lines of code!